# Elastic Search Group By multiple fields with filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I have data in the format as shown in the image below. I have to get the aggs on sectionId and the name(only in en language).

[image]

I am trying nested aggs using filter on the 'en' language as shown in the image below:

[image]

But I am getting the aggs by sectionId and sectionnames. SectionId is correct but the SectionName is returning in all 3 languages but I only need in one language('en')

[image]

Comment: This is the only example I've found till now with multi fields nested aggregations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

elasticsearch do not treat array of objects as you think:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html

If `section.names` is not `nested`, this will not work.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, it works fine now, as soon I made the names array as nested :)

Comment: @GSH if this answer is correct, please mark it as resolved!